# Uniting two pieces of one table, then joining with a column of an other table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have a problem which I can't solve.

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Gas
(
    ID int, 
    Datum date, 
    Time_ time, 
    m3 float, 
    total float
);
    
INSERT INTO Gas (ID, Datum, Time_, m3, total)
VALUES
    (1,'2022-11-04','00:00:00',NULL, 1999.5),
    (2,'2022-11-05','00:00:00',NULL, 2000.7),
    (3,'2022-11-06','00:00:00',NULL, 2002.5),
    (4,'2022-11-07','00:00:00',NULL, 2004.7),
    (5,'2022-11-07','07:00:00', 0.3,NULL),
    (6,'2022-11-07','08:00:00', 0.4,NULL),
    (7,'2022-11-07','09:00:00', 1.0,NULL),
    (8,'2022-11-07','10:00:00', 0.1,NULL),
    (9,'2022-11-08','07:00:00', 0.2,NULL),
    (10,'2022-11-08','08:00:00', 0.5,NULL),
    (11,'2022-11-08','09:00:00', 0.9,NULL),
    (12,'2022-11-08','10:00:00', 0.5,NULL);

CREATE TABLE temps
(
    Datum date, 
    temp float
);
    
INSERT INTO temps (Datum, temp)
VALUES
    ('2022-11-02', 10.5),
    ('2022-11-03', 12.5),
    ('2022-11-04', 10.2),
    ('2022-11-05', 10.5),
    ('2022-11-06', 12.5),
    ('2022-11-07', 10.2),
    ('2022-11-08', 11.8),
    ('2022-11-09', 9.0),
    ('2022-11-10', 10.1),
    ('2022-11-11', 11.7);
```

You'll see, that the first table has either total-counter or increments.

Now I want to do a sum - to get all increments.

```
SELECT 
    total - LAG(total) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS sum_Gas,    
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(' ', g.Datum)) AS sum_date 
FROM 
    Gas AS g 
WHERE 
    g.total > 0
UNION
SELECT 
    SUM(`m3`) AS sum_Gas, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(' ', Datum)) AS sum_date 
FROM 
    Gas 
WHERE 
    DATE(`Datum`) BETWEEN DATE_SUB( DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 year) AND DATE(NOW()) 
    AND m3 > 0 
GROUP BY 
    sum_date
```

This works on my server - not in a MySQL simulator.

So I go further with:

```
SELECT 
    total AS sum_Gas, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(' ', g.Datum)) AS sum_date 
FROM 
    Gas AS g 
WHERE 
    g.total > 0
UNION
SELECT 
    SUM(`m3`) AS sum_Gas, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(' ', Datum)) AS sum_date 
FROM 
    Gas 
WHERE 
    DATE(`Datum`) BETWEEN DATE_SUB( DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 year) AND DATE(NOW()) 
    AND m3 > 0 
GROUP BY 
    sum_date
```

and pretend these are all increments in my output:

```
sum_Gas     sum_date
----------------------
1.20        1667520000
1.80        1667606400
2.20        1667692800
1.80        1667779200
2.10        1667865600
```

Okay - now I have my kubic-meters gas and I want to correlate it with an other table called "temps"

Here I'm stuck.

How to merge this **UNION** with a **JOIN** where I want to grab the temperatures of the second table?

In reality I have about 140 measurements per day - and do the average as follows:

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG(`AussenTemp`), 2) AS avg_Temp, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(' ', Datum)) AS sum_date
FROM 
    `temps`
WHERE 
    DATE(`Datum`) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 year) AND DATE(NOW())
GROUP BY 
    sum_date;
```

Can anyone suggest a syntax to generate a result set like this:

```
sum_Gas     sum_date    avg_temp
--------------------------------
1.20        1667520000  10.2
1.80        1667606400  10.5
2.20        1667692800  12.5
1.80        1667779200  10.2
2.10        1667865600  11.8
```

?

It doesn't has to go into a new table - it is a query from php to plot.

I've tried both parts - get the average temps of one table sorted by date, and the daily sums sorted by date.

Because of that one table contains both - totals and increments, I have to do a UNION to the first table. this doesn't seem to match to the join.

I tried to do the join first and then the UNION throws an error

> Unknown column 'temps.temp' in 'field list'`

or some variation of a syntax error around ON on JOIN

```
SELECT 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(' ', g.Datum)) AS sum_date, 
    g.total - LAG(g.total) OVER (ORDER BY g.ID) AS sum_Gas, 
    ROUND(AVG(`s.temp`),2) AS avg_Temp 
FROM 
    Gas AS g, temps AS s 
INNER JOIN 
    StallDB ON g.Datum = s.Datum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select sb.*, t.* from (
SELECT 
    g.total AS sum_Gas, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(g.datum) AS sum_date,
    g.Datum
FROM gas AS g 
WHERE g.total > 0
UNION 
SELECT SUM(`m3`) AS sum_Gas, 
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Datum) AS sum_date,
    Datum
FROM Gas 
WHERE DATE(`Datum`) BETWEEN DATE_SUB( DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 year) AND DATE(NOW()) 
      AND m3 > 0 
GROUP BY sum_date) sb
join temps t on sb.datum = t.datum;
```

Let me know if it helped you

Comment: oh, I see. you joined the two tables and defined a new one out of these by using the brackets. Thanks!